# Taking Multiple inputs in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I just began learning C++ and had a rookie question.

Suppose I am given an input separated by spaces ex `2 4 56` or `2 1 10 15` or `hi bye ok`. 
How can I store the values in an array as the length of input is not know.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on `std::vector`. It can grow to the size needed.

Answer (score 1):

search for spaces and split the string in each space as the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


vector<string> GetInputs(string s)
{
    vector<size_t> foundSpacesPositions;
    vector<string> results;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isspace(s[i]))
        {
            foundSpacesPositions.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    size_t start = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < foundSpacesPositions.size(); i++)
    {
        if (foundSpacesPositions[i] == start)
        {
            ++start;
            continue;
        }
        results.push_back(s.substr(start, foundSpacesPositions[i] - start));
        start = foundSpacesPositions[i] + 1;
    }
    if (start < s.length() - 1)
        results.push_back(s.substr(start, s.length() - 1));
    return results;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string s = "a dd 8 ll ehh fd $%^ &   89 . ";

    vector<string> results = GetInputs(s);
    for (auto& res : results)
    {
        cout << res << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
/* OUTPUT
a
dd
8
ll
ehh
fd
$%^
&
89
.
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the input is given as a string, you can easily use a `std::istringstream`. If the input is given in stdin, you can just use the `std::cin` stream. `std::istream`'s `operator<<` will take integers from a string using spaces as a default delimiter. Once you've read all the input on the stream, `std::istream`'s `operator bool` will return false, and you can stop reading.

An example implementation would be:

```
vector<int> getIntsFromString(const string& s) {
    istringstream ss(s);
    int i;
    vector<int> result;
    while (ss >> i) result.push_back(i);
    return move(result);
}
```

Suppose you are getting multiple lines with a variable number of integers from stdin, and you want to store them in `vector<int>`'s. You can do something similar to:

```
string buf;
while (getline(cin, buf)) {
    auto v = getIntsFromString(buf);
    for (auto i : v) cout << i << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```